# Conga Mail Merge parameters in url

Tags: merge, conga, parameters

I'm trying to get Conga Composer to work. I want to generate a mail merge, where, in Conga, the user is given the option of selecting which records are to be merged.

I have a button on a custom object with the following URL:

```
https://massmerge.appextremes.com/apps/Conga/Welcome.aspx?SessionId={!API.Session_ID}&ServerUrl={!API.Partner_Server_URL_80}&Id={!MasterCustomObject__c.Id}&QueryId=a0wm0000000DMNJ
```

I have a conga query (a0wm0000000DMNJ) that selects fields from the (detail) custom object, matching the id with pv0:

```
SELECT MasterCustomObject__r.Field1__c, MasterCustomObject__r.Field2__c, MasterCustomObject__r.Field3__c, Contact__r.Name, Contact__r.MailingCity, Contact__r.MailingCountry, Contact__r.MailingState, Contact__r.MailingPostalCode, Contact__r.MailingStreet FROM DetailCustomObject__c WHERE MasterCustomObject__c={pv0}
```

It seems like the 'id' GET parameter is not legitimate for "massmerge.appextremes.com...." and it is not finding its way into pv0, I get this on step 2 of Conga Mail Merge:

```
"INVALID_QUERY_FILTER_OPERATOR: count() FROM DetailCustomObject__c WHERE MasterCustomObject__r.Id = '{pv0}' ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:40 invalid ID field: {pv0}"
```

So how can I generate a mail merge for specific records? I need a way to inject a parameter something into the query. Hard coding an id (for MasterCustomObject__c) *will* work.

NB. the query above will work for a point merge, but there's no option to select which records ultimately get merged.

I'm using Conga Composer 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'id' GET is not supported in Conga Mail Merge.  The challenge here is that you should really be using Conga Composer / Conductor for your desired solution, not Conga Mail Merge.  Conga Conductor is an option add-on that allows you to construct a merge solution from a List View and then simply select the records you would like to merge against.

Documentation can be found here on how to convert a Composer solution to Conductor and then tie Conductor to a List View: [http://knowledge.congasphere.com/congakb/wf/uploadfiles/files/Conga%20Conductor%20(Release%208).pdf](http://knowledge.congasphere.com/congakb/wf/uploadfiles/files/Conga%20Conductor%20%28Release%208%29.pdf)